# how to fix UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, fs, catch-block

I am trying to fix my error but i don't know how. i have researched around looking for node `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` but i haven't been able to fix it.

```
function getBandsInTown(artist) {

    var artist = userInput;
    var bandQueryURL = "https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/" + artist + "/events?app_id=codingbootcamp"

    axios.get(bandQueryURL).then(
        function (response) {
            console.log("=============================");
            console.log("Name of the venue: " + response.data[0].venue.name + "\r\n");
            console.log("Venue Location: " + response.data[0].venue.city + "\r\n");
            console.log("Date of event: " + moment(response.data[0].datetime).format("MM-DD-YYYY") + "\r\n");

            var logConcert = "======Begin Concert Log Entry======" + "\nName of the musician: " + artist + "\nName of the venue: " + response.data[0].venue.name + "\nVenue location: " + response.data[0].venue.city + "\n Date of event: " + moment(response.data[0].datetime).format("MM-DD-YYYY") + "\n======End Concert Log Entry======" + "\n";

            fs.appendFile("log.txt", logConcert, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
            })

            // logResults(response.data)
        });
```

> (node:18908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'venue' of undefined
>       at C:\Users\Aaron Lanier\gt\sandbox\liri-node-app\liri.js:104:66
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>   (node:18908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>
> (node:18908) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: add catch after then. ex: - ```axios.get(url).then(----).catch(err=>{           console.log(err);
          })```;

Comment: also useful `console.log(response);` right after `function (response) {`

Comment: This is not the cause of the error you write about, but this `if (err) throw err;` inside a plain async callback is NEVER appropriate code.  It does nothing useful.  Write real error handling.

Answer (score 1):

Add .catch method after then. also you are facing issue because data[0] is not defined. please try to console response to see which are properties are available to you in response object.